# Can CRM OrgService and Context be static?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

This is design question/query so I hope it's Ok to post...

Pretty much every CRM OrgService and Context example you see is not static. Normally uses a `using` block. Which works of course, but could this be a static class rather than creating/destroying this over and over and over with using blocks everywhere? Is there any issue doing this?

Thanks for your advice :-)

**Edit: Here's the code. Do you see any issue with this?...**

`CrmServiceContext` is created by the early-bound entities generator.

```
static public class CRMOrgService
{
    static private IOrganizationService _orgService = null;
    static private CrmServiceContext _context = null;

    static public IOrganizationService OrgService {
        get
        {
            if (_orgService == null)
            {
                var reader = new AppSettingsReader();
                Uri crmUri = new Uri(reader.GetValue("CRMOrgSvc", typeof(string)).ToString());
                string crmUser = reader.GetValue("CRMUser", typeof(string)).ToString();
                string crmPass = reader.GetValue("CRMPass", typeof(string)).ToString();
                // Your client credentials   
                ClientCredentials clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
                clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = crmUser;
                clientCredentials.UserName.Password = crmPass;
                // Create your Organization Service Proxy  
                var proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(crmUri, null, clientCredentials, null);
                proxy.EnableProxyTypes();
                _orgService = (IOrganizationService)proxy;
            }

            return _orgService;
        }
    }

    static public CrmServiceContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context == null)
            {
                _context = new CrmServiceContext(OrgService);
            }
            return _context;
        }
    }

    static public void CloseCleanUp() 
    {
        _context.ClearChanges();
        _context.Dispose();
        _context = null;
        _orgService = null;
    }

} // end class
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be static. However, you have to keep in mind this instance will not be thread safe. This means, the connection instance can not be used simultaneous by multiple threads.

Comment: So this would or would not be OK in a WindowsService app?